# checksum mismatch on subversion merge

Tags: svn, merge, checksum, mismatch

I'm using Subversion 1.6.17 on a SuSE host to try and merge a single branch into a local updated working copy.  I'm getting portions of the merge, then it stops on the same file every time I try with:

```
svn: Checksum mismatch for 'path/to/javascript/files/myjavascriptfile.js':
    expected checksum:  685b3a63667d3eb4cc4a09ccc960ea2c
    actual checksum:    7c4dfb8a7065aa2c616a1680c1703914
```

I've checked the .svn/text-base/ version of the file, and md5sum shows the correct "expected" checksum, as does an md5sum of the actual file.  I've even checked out the source branch of the merge and md5sum'd it there, too, and I get the same checksum.  However, when I try to merge from the source branch into the working copy of the target branch, I get the error above.  If I edit the file and make a trivial change, I can commit it without error; it just seems to be the merge process that's not cooperating.

I've tried the tricks of rm'ing the folder and svn update to re-populate it, I've tried the  "edit the entries file and change to the actual checksum returned" method, all with no luck.  I've also ran an svnadmin verify on the repository, with no errors.

I've also checked the svn properties associated with both the file and it's folder and all I see are the expected svn:mergeinfo properties with previous revisions that successfully merged.

Anyone have any suggestions on what to try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow-up - the same merge on two different boxes merges successfully, so I need to see if something is proxying http traffic on the subnet where this box resides.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130/repair-svn-checksum

Bassam