# svn: Checksum mismatch

Tags: svn, merge, checksum, mismatch

This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769496/checksum-mismatch-on-subversion-merge), but that question was never answered.

I'm merging changes from trunk into a feature branch.  During the merge, I run into the following error:

```
svn: Checksum mismatch for 'projs/Services/TestPage.html':
   expected checksum:  cc53fe9f106b5f7fffe52ff7d1833b43
   actual checksum:    ca458ae559e2c3b5adba630e078e98df

svn: Error reading spooled REPORT request response
```

I've confirmed the checksum on the file:

```
$ md5sum TestPage.html
cc53fe9f106b5f7fffe52ff7d1833b43
```

I've also check .svn/entries file and verified it has the same checksum.  From that standpoint, everything matches.

Finally, I've followed the general advice for fixing this problem and deleted my working directory, then checked it out again.  That did not work.  Neither did trying the process on a different machine.

Is there a way to either fix this problem or convince the merge to skip it and move on?  I would be fine manually updating the file as it is non-essential for the feature branch.

```
In case this helps, the SVN version is:

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Jun 26 2013, 20:44:02
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repair SVN Checksum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130/repair-svn-checksum)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question because I'm not trying to commit.  This problem is happening on an 'svn merge' command.  Google is full of answers on how to fix the commit problem, but I'm not having luck solving the merge problem.

Comment: Do you mean that if you check out a fresh working copy and proceed again, you still get the same error message?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Don't intentionally create duplicate questions. See [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for why this problem happened or the "proper" way to fix it, but I did find a workaround that might be helpful.  Here's what I did:

1. Manually merged the parent of TestPage.html from trunk into the feature branch.
2. Ran 'svn merge --record-only' on the parent directory.  This marks the files as merged without making any changes besides changing the merge info.

After that I was able to complete the merge as normal.